# Change color of Rect html Canvas in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to create a program that shows the steps of sorting algorithms, like that:

https://visualgo.net/bn/sorting

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRA0W1kECg

Now, I dont know how I can change the color of my rectangles that i'm comparing

For example, when the `array[i]` compare to `array[i+1]` I want to change these colors (green and red... an example)

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var array = [10, 150, 17, 200, 300, 110, 400, 260, 105, 157, 180, 208, 400, 122, 40, 266, 123];

drawnLines(array);

function sleep(ts) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(resolve, ts)
  })
}

async function init() {
  const it = bubbleSort(array)
  let result = it.next()

  while (!result.done) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 500)
    drawnLines(array);
    result = it.next();
    await sleep(500)
  }
  console.log('finished!')
}

function drawnLines(array) {
  let height;
  let position = 5;

  ctx.font = "10px Verdana";

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    height = array[i];
    ctx.fillRect(position, 5, 20, height);
    ctx.strokeText(array[i].toString(), position, array[i] + 20);
    ctx.stroke();
    position += 48;
  }
};

function* bubbleSort(array) {
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
      if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
        yield
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
};
```

```css
#myCanvas {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
}

.rectangle {
    width: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>BubbleSort</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
</head>

<body>
    
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
    
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>

    <button type="button" onclick="init()">Bubble Sort</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can use ` ctx.fillStyle ` to change the color

Comment: but that change all rectangles. I want to manipulate just one.

Answer (score 0):

The fillStyle command can change the color of the rectangles!
For example, in your drawLines function,

```
function drawnLines(array) {
  let height;
  let position = 5;

  ctx.font = "10px Verdana";

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    height = array[i];
    //Here you can enter in a color!
    ctx.fillStyle = "#eee";

    ctx.fillRect(position, 5, 20, height);
    ctx.strokeText(array[i].toString(), position, array[i] + 20);
    ctx.stroke();
    position += 48;
  }
};
```

It can be hex or the color name.
If you want the rectangles to be different, you can use make a random color generator, or use an array to help a set value of colors and loop through that array while drawing the rectangles, as such:

```
var mySetColors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "#eee"];
var myLocation = 0;

for()...
ctx.fillStyle = mySetColors[myLocation++];
...
```

You can refer to this site for more in-detail explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillstyle.asp